# iOS: Augmented Reality support through Mobile Web page

Tags: ios, mobile-website, augmented-reality

I have a Mobile web page (on an iPhone), where-in I have a button called ‘launch camera’. Clicking on this button in Safari browser, will launch native device camera. It is done using this code,  . It runs like a pure web application. Now, I want to introduce augmented reality way of displaying video. When I track an image using device camera, it should play a respected video. I have earlier done this natively integrated with Metaio, Qualcomm vuforia etc. But, I need to do this in the mobile web page, not through native or hybrid, my requirement is that. How can I integrate scan (track) an image and play respected video an augmented reality way through a Mobile web page and device camera?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. iOS browser won't let you access the live image from your camera and draw on top of the view finder.